# Trimming spaces while still keeping words

Tags: java, string

I have a data file that contains `String` inputs like the following:

```
Tour    g
tour i
stall    2
 venue 2
```

and I need to trim the spaces down for proper comparison:

```
for(int l=0; l<listOfFacilities.size(); l++)
{

   String tempFacName = listOfFacilities.get(l).getFacilityName(); //string to be compared to
   if(tempFacName.contains(facility.toLowerCase() )==true) //facility is the string from above taken from an imput file
        System.out.println("true");

}
```

but I was wondering if there was any way to trim the spaces before, after, and inbetween but still retain one space in the middle. to turn ( venue 2 ) into (venue 2)? I understand how to use .replace() and .replaceAll() to trim all the spaces down, however I want to avoid turning all my strings into (venue2), (tourg), etc. any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try like this:

```
tempFacName = tempFacName.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

This replaces every whitespace with a space and then removes spaces from the beginning and the end of the String.

See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) for `String.trim()`